# ¿Forma correcta de importar librerías JS en Laravel con laravel mix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, javascript-import

Cuento con varios js minificados de librerías que estoy usando.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de incorporarlos a tu vistas en Laravel?

Ya que al agregarlos con etiquetas como es lo convencional:

```
<script src="/public/js/lib.min.js">
```

Laravel me arroja una alerta y me dice que lo recomendable seria agregar por mix laravel.

Tengo mi mix.scripts de la siguiente manera pero el output me arroja una hoja vacía.

```
mix.scripts([
   'assets/js/plugin/webfont/webfont.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/chart.js/chart.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/chart-circle/circles.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js',
   'assets/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js',
   'assets/js/atlantis.min.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Luego de generar el fichero `all.js` ¿cómo lo agrego a mi *front*? ¿estaría bien asi?

```
<scrtit src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que las librerías las instales con un gestor de paquetes como npm o yarn, y luego las importes en tus componentes.

Te paso un ejemplo de la [documentación](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/jquery-ui) de Laravel-mix para la librería jQuery UI, que veo que es una de la que quieres usar. Luego sería lo mismo para las otras.

Construye tu configuración

```
// webpack.mix.js 

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Instala jquery-ui (nota que para que funcione, antes tienes que haber instalado jQuery `npm install jquery`, o puedes hacerlo todo en una línea `npm install jquery jquery-ui`)

```
npm install jquery-ui --save-dev
```

Importa el widget que desees usar

```
// resources/js/app.js

import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
```

Importa el CSS

```
// resources/sass/app.scss

@import '~jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
```

Lanza el UI Plugin

```
// resources/js/app.js

$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

En blade deberás tener algo así ( al ejemplo de datepicker lo tomé de [aquí](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) ):

```
<head>
     <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    Fecha:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker">
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que puedo ver es que estás generando un archivo llamado `all.js`, pero estás consultando en el blade `app.js`

Adicionalmente, estoy sumiendo que ya corriste el comando `$ yarn dev` o `$ npm run dev`, lo digo porque comentas que el archivo está vacio.

Comment: Me equivoque al escribir, me referia al all.js ahi cargo todo mis libs externas, app solo para la logica de vue
Si estoy corriendo todo run dev, la pregunta en si es como es la forma correcta de importar archivos js externos si ya los tengo minificados

Los guardo directo en public/js  y los llamo al final de blade? (Cuando hago eso me dice un error en consola: 

app.js:38138 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.