# quiero agregar jquery y bootstrap a laravel 6

Tags: laravel

ya lo intente por medio de webpack y me marco error y lo hice

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

        <title>Componentes</title>



        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> GET http://sistema.test/js/toastr.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>       dashboard:57 GET http://sistema.test/js/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>       dashboard:55 GET http://sistema.test/js/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>       app.js:13246 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>           at Object../resources/js/bootstrap.js (app.js:13246)
>           at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>           at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:13187)
>           at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>           at Object.0 (app.js:15629)
>           at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>           at app.js:84
>           at app.js:87
>       ./resources/js/bootstrap.js @ app.js:13246
>       **webpack_require** @ app.js:20
>       ./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:13187
>       **webpack_require** @ app.js:20
>       0 @ app.js:15629
>       **webpack_require** @ app.js:20
>       (anonymous) @ app.js:84
>       (anonymous) @ app.js:87
>       dashboard:57 GET http://sistema.test/js/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>       dashboard:58 GET http://sistema.test/js/toastr.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ¿Qué error obtuviste al agregarlo?

Comment: lo acabo de poner perdon

Comment: si detecta mi archivo app.js pero bootstrap o jquery no ya lo intente por webpack pero me sale error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guiarte por como lo hacían en versiones anteriores de Laravel. Por ejemplo en la versión 5.6, Laravel por default traía jquery 3.2 y bootstrap 4 si querías usar el andamiaje front-end.

El código relevante sería el siguiente:

[package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/package.json)
*En este, sólo ten en cuenta que las versiones ya son viejas, por ejemplo `laravel-mix`, así que puedes mantener las que trae [Laravel 6.x](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json) y quitar lo que no vayas a usar, para el ejemplo sólo comentaré las líneas de `vue` y `axios` pero puedes eliminarlas directamente, ya que la pregunta es sobre `jquery` y `bootstrap`.*

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        // ... lo que va aquí no cambia nada
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        // "axios": "^0.18", "^0.19" en Laravel 6.x
        "cross-env": "^5.1", // "^7.0" en Laravel 6.x
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0", // "^5.0.1" en Laravel 6.x
        "lodash": "^4.17.5" //, "^4.17.13" en Laravel 6.x
        // "vue": "^2.5.7" // "^2.6.10" en Laravel 6.x
    }
}
```

[/resources/assets/js/app.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/resources/assets/js/app.js)

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

// window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

// const app = new Vue({
//    el: '#app'
// });
```

[/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js)

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

// window.axios = require('axios');

// window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

// let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

// if (token) {
    // window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
// } else {
    // console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
// }
```

[/resources/assets/sass/app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/resources/assets/sass/app.scss)

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

[webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/webpack.mix.js)

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Teniendo esos archivos, es sólo correr los comandos npm y todo debería salir andando sin problema.

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Finalmente, en tu vista principal cargas los archivos compilados:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">    


        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

También [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310408/forma-correcta-de-importar-js-de-liberias-en-laravel-con-laravel-mix/310481#310481) te puede ayudar a entender cómo importar librerías.