# Problema al compilar Laravel MIX

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Estoy queriendo implementar un datepicker en uno de mis formularios. Para lo cual entro al ejemplo de datepiker de la web de Jquery

[Web Jquery / Datepiker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)

Paro eso copio y pego el siguiente ejemplo - Archivos de importacion de Jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Script

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Esto anda genial, el problema lo tengo cuando quiero hacer un solo archivo js con laravel MIX

Mi archivo WebPack

```
mix.scripts([
'resources/js/jquery.js',
'resources/js/popper.min.js',
'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'resources/js/friconix.js',
], 'public/js/app.js')
```

Mi archivo Body

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    @include('layouts.navbar')

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

@yield('scripts')
</body>
```

Esto hace que deje de andar el datapiker. La unica forma que encontre para que funcione es agregando debajo de la linea donde se importa el archivo app.js la siguiente 2 lineas

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Nose cuando corro npm run dev, se genera el app.js pero no funciona el datepiker

Comment: te da algún error el compilador?

Comment: Ninguno. Genera hasta el app.js y todo

Comment: Prueba importando las librerías en app.js en vez de compilarlas. Dale una mirada a estas respuestas https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/310481/92278 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/332451/92278

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme de esa forma